# get my dhcp server ip address

Tags: c#, network-programming

My DHCP servers address is 192.168.0.1

But, I am assuming that other networks can have a different IP address for their DHCP server.

what is a good way to get my networks DHCP server IP address in C#

I have looked under the

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation
```

but cannot see anything I can call for this.

I suspect this is a simple thing to do as well?

Thanks

Comment: Its more likely under [System.Net.Dns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Dns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Guess I was wrong, the answers below look like it, information is in [IPInterfaceProperties.DhcpServerAddresses Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is under `System.Net.NetworkInformation`

Comment: When you said Dns it made sense to me and you woud l have thought it would have been there too! thanks for commenting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("DHCP Servers");
NetworkInterface[] adapters  = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{

    IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    IPAddressCollection addresses = adapterProperties.DhcpServerAddresses;
    if (addresses.Count >0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
        foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Dhcp Address ............................ : {0}", 
                address.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

More info: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dhcpserveraddresses%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I did do a Process on DOS Ipconfig /all which also gave me the DHCP but I had to parse the output. This way is cleaner :)

Answer (score 3):

Information about a DHCP server that provided a IP address is interface specific since you can have multiple interfaces on the host, each of them connected to  a different network with different DHCP servers. This information should be under a `IPInterfaceProperties.DhcpServerAddresses` based on the MSDN documentation. The sample code from their docs:

```
public static void DisplayDhcpServerAddresses()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DHCP Servers");
    NetworkInterface[] adapters  = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
    {

        IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        IPAddressCollection addresses = adapterProperties.DhcpServerAddresses;
        if (addresses.Count >0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
            foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Dhcp Address ............................ : {0}", 
                    address.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks.  does work but the answer above got there 1st.Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

With `System.Linq`, you can make this even simpler:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetDhcpServers() =>
   NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().
   SelectMany(i => i.GetIPProperties().DhcpServerAddresses).Distinct();
```

If you only want active servers, you can filter by the adapter's `OperationalStatus`:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetActiveDhcpServers() =>
   NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().
   Where(i => i.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up).
   SelectMany(i => i.GetIPProperties().DhcpServerAddresses).Distinct();
```